# Laravel 8x Post Routing Issue

Tags: php, laravel, routes

**Hello All.**

I am new to laravel.

```php
Route::get('/', [UserController::class, "Userindex"]);
Route::post('/', [UserController::class, "UserProcessLogin"]);
```

---

These are my routes. When I post to this route by form, it always goes to the get route in the form , my action is:

```
<form action="{{url('/')}}" method="post">
```

But Post Route is not working, this is working with the other route, but not with the same route.
When I Test the same process with Postman Or thunder Client, they are returning Good results, as I worked.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `action=""` in `form`.
Use like this:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through  Laravel 8 documentation
Also use other url for post method like

```
Route::post('/login',[UserController::class,"UserProcessLogin"]);
```